# Laravel and SQL wherein Orwhere where doesn't restrict

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I think this is an easy one, but driving me a bit crazy

I have this:

```
Transaction::
    where('seller_id', $this->id)->
    Orwhere('buyer_id', $this->id )->
    whereIn('concept', ['Lemonway','Paypal'])->
    where('status', '=', 'ok')
    ->get();
```

So if I'm clearly specifying `status = 'ok'`

Why is picking a `status = Pending transaction`?

Comment: I know nothing about this syntax, but isn't it possible that one of the 3 where conditions that come before the ('status', '=', 'ok) could result in a row where the status = Pending Transaction?

Comment: The operator precedence is `NOT/AND/OR`, your syntax probably result in `(...) OR status = 'ok'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) for parameter grouping, for example:

```
Transaction::where(function($q) {
        $q->where('seller_id', $this->id)
          ->orwhere('buyer_id', $this->id)
          ->whereIn('concept', ['Lemonway', 'Paypal']);
    })
    ->where('status', 'ok')
    ->get();
```